# Flutter: Real ads doesn't work on release mode

Tags: flutter, admob

I have added my device id to admob console as test device.

When I build apk and install it on my test device, the ads work fine, But on other devices not.

I have searched a lot but there is no answer.

**I used:**

```
native_admob_flutter: ^1.5.0
```

**Flutter doctor:**

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1348], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.5.2 at C:\Src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 3595343e20 (3 months ago), 2021-09-30 12:58:18 -0700
    • Engine revision 6ac856380f
    • Dart version 2.14.3
```

**How can I know if this happen because of console or my flutter code?**

Answer (score 1):

Its not from your code its from your Ads serving company or Admob.

You have to add the other device as a test device otherwise you need to make your App reviewed if not it will rarely shows ads.